# Getting selected text with CKEditor Plugin on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, plugins, ckeditor

I have made a plugin for CKEditor, but it relies on the currently selected text.

In FF and Chrome I can use:

```
var selectedText = editor.getSelection().getNative();
```

but this doesn't work in IE and I only get `[object Object]`

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you care for HTML look at the answer by user6269864 below

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
var mySelection = editor.getSelection();

if (CKEDITOR.env.ie) {
    mySelection.unlock(true);
    selectedText = mySelection.getNative().createRange().text;
} else {
    selectedText = mySelection.getNative();
}
```

Comment: OK, that looks good, but where do I put that in my dialog code? I thought it would be under onShow:function( HERE ) but I get the error that selectedText is undefined when I use the code below in the contents section.

    type:'html',
    html:selectedText

Answer (score 18):

**Use:**

```
editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
```

**Or:**

```
CKEDITOR.instances["txtTexto"].getSelection().getSelectedText()
```

"txtTexto" = ID of textarea tag

Answer (score 5):

To those who want to prefill fields with a selection, just do it like that and safe yourself a long journey.

```
onShow: function() {
    this.setValueOf( 'tab-id', 'field-id', editor.getSelection().getSelectedText().toString() );
},
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

In the newer versions of CKEDITOR, there seems to be a way easier method:

```
var selectedHTML = editor
                      .getSelectedHtml()
                      .getHtml(); //result: <p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

@TheApprentice

You put it like this:

```
( function(){

  var getSelectedText = function(editor) {
    var selectedText = '';
    var selection = editor.getSelection();
    if (selection.getType() == CKEDITOR.SELECTION_TEXT) {
      if (CKEDITOR.env.ie) {
        selection.unlock(true);
        selectedText = selection.getNative().createRange().text;
      } else {
        selectedText = selection.getNative();
      }
    }
    return(selectedText);
  }

...
```

with a call like this:

```
onShow: function() {
  // Get the element currently selected by the user
  var editor = this.getParentEditor();
  var selectedContent = getSelectedText(editor);
```