# How to get selected html from CKEDITOR in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

I am having problem to get selected html written in ckeditor in javascript in my drupal project. can any one help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting selected text win CKEditor Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385609/getting-selected-text-win-ckeditor-plugin)

Comment: @ManseUK: Not a duplicate: this question asks for the selected HTML, not the selected text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CKEditor's API doesn't provide exactly this, but looking at [the docs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.range.html#cloneContents) it looks as though you could do the following (untested):

```
function getSelectionHtml(editor) {
    var sel = editor.getSelection();
    var ranges = sel.getRanges();
    var el = new CKEDITOR.dom.element("div");
    for (var i = 0, len = ranges.length; i < len; ++i) {
        el.append(ranges[i].cloneContents());
    }
    return el.getHtml();
}

alert( getSelectionHtml(editor) );
```

CKEditor also has HTML parsing and serialization APIs that I don't know much about, so you may be able to use those to tailor the HTML to your requirements rather than use the raw output from the browser's `innerHTML` implementation.

Comment: this code produce this error
Error: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLDivElement.appendChild]
[Break On This Error]  

el.appendChild(ranges[i].cloneContents());

Comment: @AbubakarShams: Should be fixed now.