# CKEditor plugin - Proper way to iterate multiple DOM elements for selected text

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have the following selected text in CKEditor plugin.

```
monkey needs <span answer="banana">food</span> today
```

I can retrieve the `banana` using the following code

```
editor.on( 'dialogShow', function( dialogShowEvent )
{
    var selection = editor.getSelection();
    if (selection) {
        var selectedElement = selection.getSelectedElement();
        // http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/GetSelectedElement-returns-null-IE-and-Chrome-BUG
        if (selectedElement == null) {
            // I have no idea whether this is a correct workaround? Just pray...
            selectedElement = selection.getStartElement();
        }
        if (selectedElement == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Yes :)
        var banana = selectedElement.getAttribute('answer');
```

However, the code will break, if our selected text is

```
monkey needs <span answer="banana"><strong>food</strong></span> today
```

May I know what is the correct way to iterate through DOM element of selected text? I expect we have something like `getSelectedElements` (Plural). But, I can't find one.

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385609/getting-selected-text-win-ckeditor-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check all elements starting from [`selection.getStartElement()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection-method-getStartElement) down to [`editor.editable()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable), then you can use the [`dom.elementPath`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath).

```
var elementPath = editor.elementPath();
var answerElement = elementPath.contains( function( el ) {
    return el.hasAttribute( 'answer' );
} );
```

If, on the other hand, you want to traverse the DOM tree in DFS order (source order), then you will want to use the [`dom.walker`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.walker):

```
var range = sel.getRanges()[ 0 ],
    walker = new CKEDITOR.dom.walker( range ),
    node;

while ( ( node = walker.next() ) ) {
    // .. do something
}
```

Depending on a case you may want to do dozen of other things, so I can't describe all of them. There's many methods for in the [`dom.range`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range) class, [`dom.element`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element) or [`dom.iterator`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.iterator).