# Get selected text from ckeditor in django python

Tags: python, django, text, ckeditor, selected

Are there any good ways to get the selected text from a ckeditor RichTextField as a python string in django? Apologies if this question has been asked before but I could not find any results when it came to ckeditor and django.

Comment: Keep in mind that CKEditor is a client-side JavaScript control, whereas Django is a server-side framework for processing HTTP requests. When you edit a rich text field in CKEditor, it writes the HTML to an input box in your form. When you submit your form, that HTML is submitted with it. You can then use Django to retrieve the form content. Django isn't actually aware of CKEditor; it accesses the content the same way it would any other input field in your form. Does that make sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting selected text with CKEditor Plugin on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385609/getting-selected-text-with-ckeditor-plugin-on-ie)